# how to remove unwanted row in dataFrame coverting to csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file that contains large amount of data,but the data that contained in csv file is not cleaned.The example of csv data is as follows

```
 country     branch      no_of_employee     total_salary    count_DOB   count_email
      x            a            30                 2500000        20            25
      x            b            20                 350000         15            20
      y            c            30                 4500000        30            30
      z            d            40                 5500000        40            40
      z            e            10                 1000000        10            10
      z            f            15                 1500000        15            15
```

after applying the group by i am  getting the proper result .

```
df = data_df.groupby(['country']).count()
```

but one extra row is in the dataFrame. Showing one extra row with following contents

```
8  lines terminated by \n\t" ignore 1 lines;       2                0
```

Why it happened ?? due to error in the csv file
How to remove it??

Comment: It is very problematic found error without data. Is posible share real data?

Comment: @jezrael sorry the file size is 200MB, the data is in the same format as i mentioned above

Comment: Ok, so bad lines create  function `to_csv` or `read_csv`?

Comment: @jezrael   df.to_csv("test.csv", sep=' , ' , encoding='utf-8')

Comment: Have you tried playing with the `lineterminator` parameter of the `read_csv`method ?

Comment: @RomainX.4  no i did not use lineterminator parameter

Comment: So it is only the last line?

Comment: @Padraic ya it is onlly last line

Comment: Maybe try `import csv` and add parameter to function `to_csv` `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`